# Gulp task: get files with wiredep concatenate other js files and minify

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to build a gulp task that get all bower_components files with wiredep, then concatenates them together. Then concatenate some other JS files I have on a special folder an finally minify everything.

The problem is that I don´t know if I can specify wiredep another directory additional to the bower_components directory. If that´s not possible, is there any other solution I can use?

I´m a begginer using gulp, so any other error that you can point out in how I´m thinking my task would be highly appreciated.

```
var wiredep = require('wiredep')(
    {
      directory: 'static/bower_components', // default: '.bowerrc'.directory || bower_components
    }).stream;
gulp.task('scripts',function(){

    return gulp
        .src('index.html') //I don´t really know what to put in the src
        .pipe(wiredep())
        .pipe($.inject(gulp.src("More  JS files if wire dep can´t handle them")))
        .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('static/dist/src/app.min.js'));
});
```

Comment: What's `$`? What's `$.inject`?

Comment: It´s a gulp plugin to inject js files: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject. I don´t know if that´s the way to go about it. Any suggestions you have are welcomed :)

Comment: But that's what wiredep does, right? Injects files.

Comment: Indeed, what I don´t know  is if I can inject custom files that are outside of the bower_components files and then minify everything together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a method like this (perhaps in a config file at the root of the project) to get whatever you wanted wired in with wiredep:

```
getWiredepDefaultOptions: function() {
    var options = {
      directory: bower.directory,//file path to /bower_components/
    };
    return options;
},
```

Then in your gulp task, have something like this:

```
gulp.task('wiredep', function() {
  log('Wiring the bower dependencies into the html');

  var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
  var options = config.getWiredepDefaultOptions();

  return gulp
    .src('./index.html')
    .pipe(wiredep(options))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("wherever you want your index.html"));
});
```

Depending on what other things you want to wire in, you would have to add an ordering of some kind using tags within the index.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot this was what I needed !